# Remote Simulator to Windows option not exists

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, simulator

`Remote Simulator to Windows` option is not exists in Tools / Options / Xamarin / IOS Settings.

Its seen like this :
[image]

What I have done so far :

- I have installed the simulator from [here](http://download.xamarin.com/xamarin-simulator/Xamarin.Simulator.Installer.0.9.2.25.msi) that is from [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/) resource.
- I have already restarted both my PC and MAC Mini.
- I have activated the remote login on MAC Mini by reading the manuel.
- I have checked if the PC is connected.

What can I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is official documentation, which asserts this option must exist
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for Visual Studio updates. I had the same problem and I solved it updating Visual Studio.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 7):

It will work only on enterprise

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

```
Remoted iOS Simulator requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your voice be heard if you feel iOS Simulator should be included in other levels of VS.

https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/17194163-allow-use-of-remoted-ios-simulator-from-all-editio

Answer (score 0):

it will also work in Visual Studio Community 2017, Enterprise is not necessary.
Just Go to **tools>Extentions and Updates** and update your VS. Then you should be able to see "Remote Simulator to Windows" in tools > option > Xamarin > iOS Settings. Enjoy...